# How do I allow the user to choose between 2 options?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created 2 functions, one which calculates the maximum range of a projectile and one that calculates the maximum height of the projectile.

Now I want to write a code that let's the user choose between the above two functions.

How do I do that?

Here are the 2 functions:
    FOR RANGE

```
from math import sin
from math import pi

u = raw_input("Velocity of Projection?")
angle = raw_input("Angle of Projection?")

def max_range(u, angle):
   if type(u) == int and type(angle) == int and u>0 and angle>0:
     return " Maximum range of the projectile is " + 
str((u**2)*sin(pi/180*angle*2)*0.1)
   else:
     return "Invalid parameters!"

print max_range(u, angle)

--------------------------
FOR HEIGHT

from math import sin
from math import pi

u = raw_input("Velocity of Projection?")
angle = raw_input("Angle of Projection?")

def max_height(u, angle):
    if type(u) == int and type(angle) == int and u>0 and angle>0:
        return "Maximum height reached by the projectile is " + 
str((u**2)*(sin(pi/180*angle))**2/20)
    else:
         return "Invalid parameters!"          

print max_height(u, angle)
```

Comment: For two options, just use `if ... else`.

Comment: I never understand certain downvotes. The OP informs that is a complete newbie, shows what he/she has tried and asks how the two codes can be put together. To me looks like a perfectly valid question even if it's very basic.

Comment: I did that. I created another function which had 1 argument and the user could input it. If user chose "Range" it should return the function for range. If the user chose "Height" it should return the function for height. This did not work as it ran all the 3 functions.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by  Martijn Pieters you can use an `if...else` to decide which function to execute.

Of course you need a way of telling the program which option to execute, in my example the user is asked to input a numeric option.

```
from math import sin
from math import pi

def max_range(u, angle):
    # code that computes max range

def max_height(u, angle):
    # code that computes max height

def main():

    u = raw_input("Velocity of Projection?")
    angle = raw_input("Angle of Projection?")

    operation = raw_input("Which function to execute? 1: max_range, 2: max_height")

    if operation == 1:
        max_range(u, angle)
    elif operation == 2:
        max_height(u, angle)
    else:
        print('Invalid choice')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```